# How to use a the variable we got in a column in a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example:
Table "transactions" with columns "code,debit,credit"

Im trying to execute the query:

```
Select code, 
       Var1 = sum(debit) ,
       Var2 = sum(credit),  
       Balance_debit = Var1 - Var2, 
       Balance_credit = Var2 - Var1 
from transactions 
group by code
```

I know I can do this:

```
Select code, 
       Var1 = sum(debit) ,
       Var2 = sum(credit),  
       Balance_debit =  sum(debit) -  sum(credit), 
       Balance_credit =   sum(credit) - sum(debit) 
from transactions 
group by code
```

but I later on have very large expressions and I want to use the variable I got from the previous column.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: you can write SELECT code SUM(debit) as `@Var1` . this will store the sum of all debits in variable `@Var1`.

Comment: @KaushikKishore  yea but when you try this: select @'Var1 = sum(debit), Balance_debit = @'Var1
I get 
"A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
With CTE as
(
Select code, 
       sum(debit) as d,
       sum(credit) as c,  
       Balance_debit = Var1 - Var2, 
       Balance_credit = Var2 - Var1 
from transactions 
group by code
)
select code
    ,d as Debilt
    ,c as Credit
    ,d-c as Balance_debit 
   ,c-d as Balance_credit 
 from CTE
```

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler but I guess this is the only way.. Thanks @AK47

Comment: CTE is great option for complex queries, if you want to perform a lot of operation on your result set, it is best option.

Comment: Is it exactly the same as doing this:
select code, total_credit,total_debit, total_credit - total_debit,total_debit - total_credit from
( select code, total_credit  = sum(credit), total_debit = sum(debit) from transactions group by code
) tt